# Самодельный UIElement WPF c событием

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Хочу создать UIElement, содержащий, например, 2 стандартных эллипса:

```
public class MyUI : UIElement
{
    Ellipse el;
    Ellipse el1;
    public MyUI(Canvas canv)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        el = new Ellipse();
        el1 = new Ellipse();
        el.Width = 30;  el1.Width = 30;
        el.Height = 30; el1.Height = 30;

        el.Fill = Brushes.Green;  el1.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        canv.Children.Add(el); canv.Children.Add(el1);
        Canvas.SetTop(el, rnd.Next(300)); Canvas.SetTop(el1, rnd.Next(300));
        Canvas.SetLeft(el, rnd.Next(300)); Canvas.SetLeft(el1, rnd.Next(300));
    }
  }
```

Подскажите, как создать событие нажатия кнопки мыши по моему элементу (назовём его MyUI_MouseLeftButtonDown), которое будет срабатывать при нажатии на один из эллипсов?
 подозреваю, что можно как-то использовать стандартные события Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown для каждого из эллипсов.

Comment: Создавайте UserControl, там в xaml и пропишите все что нужно

Comment: пропишите, всё, что нужно, ну а что нужно-то прописать?

Answer (score 3):

Давайте определим свои события, которые будут генерироваться в обработчиках стандартных событий `MouseLeftButtonDown`:

```
public partial class TwoEllipses : UserControl
{
    //наше новое событие
    public event EventHandler LeftEllipseClicked;
    protected void OnLeftEllipseClicked()
    {
        if (LeftEllipseClicked != null)
        {
            LeftEllipseClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public TwoEllipses()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //обработчик стандартного события MouseLeftButtonDown
    private void Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //генерируем наше новое событие
        OnLeftEllipseClicked();            
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.TwoEllipses"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Width="115" Height="160"  Fill="Blue"
                 MouseLeftButtonDown="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown">

            </Ellipse>
            <Ellipse Width="115" Height="160"  Fill="Blue" Canvas.Left="160"
                 MouseLeftButtonDown="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown">

            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Используем:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"       
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"  >
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:TwoEllipses LeftEllipseClicked="TwoEllipses_LeftEllipseClicked"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Это всё? А когда мы вставим этот контрол в свой Window, например, нам потребуется событие `LeftEllipseClick`. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Андрей, не знаю такого события, что вы имеете ввиду? если потребуется другое события, подписыватетесь таким же способом

Comment: Ну как я понял, автору требуется создать в своём контроле события, ну например типа `LeftEllipseClick` (или как он их там назовет). А потом уже из Window иметь возможность на них подписаться. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Андрей, понял) тогда надо сделать что-то наподобие DependencyProperty для event. К сожалению не сталкивался с подобной задачей. Напишу ответ когда изучу

Comment: @Андрей, все оказалось проще)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но можно ли всё-таки унаследоваться от UIElement?
Дело в том, что если между двух эллипсов будет такой же юзерконтрол, только поменьше, то верхний юзерконтрол его накроет. мне же надо работать с этим контролом именно как с графикой.

Comment: унаследоваться можно, события нажатий как раз от элемента и наследуются.

Comment: @DmitryLeechman, если вы хотите создать свою фигуру, то нужно наследоваться от Shape. Не уверен что вам это  нужно. Опишите задачу подробнее.